# Convert all element in the nested list to integers

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a list with integers as strings so how can I convert it back

```
lst = ["['1','2']", "['2','4']", "['1','4']", "['1','5']", "['3','5']", "['3','4']"]
```

I tried to use a list comprehension

```
[j for j in i if j.isdigit() for i in lst ]
```

but it returns

```
['3', '3', '3', '3', '3', '3', '4', '4', '4', '4', '4', '4']
```

Desired output:

```
[[1,2],[2,4],[1,4],[1,5],[3,5],[3,4]]
```

Any help?

Comment: how did you end up with that ? maybe you can fix this by going a step back.

Comment: it has syntax error in `i` definition.

Comment: @Ev.Kounis That's the format I received the data.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `ast` module.

**Ex:**

```
import ast

lst = ["['1','2']", "['2','4']", "['1','4']", "['1','5']", "['3','5']", "['3','4']"]
res = [list(map(int, ast.literal_eval(i))) for i in lst]
print(res)
```

**Output:**

```
[[1, 2], [2, 4], [1, 4], [1, 5], [3, 5], [3, 4]]
```

Comment: this flattens it too. It has to be more like `res = [[int(j) for j in ast.literal_eval(i)] for i in lst]`

Comment: Oh did not see the expected output...Corrected it. Thanks.

Comment: This is the most robust solution of all proposed so far.

Answer (score 2):

Naive solution:

```
>>> lst = ["['1','2']", "['2','4']", "['1','4']", "['1','5']", "['3','5']", "['3','4']"]
>>> [[int(x.strip("'")) for x in s[1:-1].split(',')] for s in lst]
[[1, 2], [2, 4], [1, 4], [1, 5], [3, 5], [3, 4]]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use ast module's `literal_eval` function and list comprehension

```
>>>[[int(j) for j in ast.literal_eval(i)] for i in lst]

[[1, 2], [2, 4], [1, 4], [1, 5], [3, 5], [3, 4]]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
final_lst = []


for s in lst:
  sublist = []
  for item in eval(s):
     sublist.append(int(item))
  final_lst.append(sublist)

print(final_lst)
```

Answer (score 1):

you simply `eval` every list in the main list then parse every `int` inside sub lista

```
lst = ["['1','2']", "['2','4']", "['1','4']", "['1','5']", "['3','5']", "['3','4']"]
x = [[int(j) for j in eval(i)] for i in lst]
print (x)
```

output

```
[[1, 2], [2, 4], [1, 4], [1, 5], [3, 5], [3, 4]]
```